# Смещение экрана Matplotlib к центру графика

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyside6

Господа программисты. Возникла проблема: делаю школьный проект по информатике "Калькулятор на Python". Сейчас делаю режим построения графиков и появилась проблема.

Вот, вроде бы всё окей:
[image: Строим параболу]

Я специально выставил лимит по `x` и `y` на 10 единиц, чтоб график не было мелкого масштаба.
Всё работает прекрасно до тех пор, пока не сдвину график по оси `y`, пусть, на 500 единиц.

[image: Помогите Даше Путешественнице найти график]

И всё: графика, будто и не было.
То беж я хотел бы, чтобы экран `matplotlib`, который я соответственно перенёс в `QVBoxLayout` в PySide6, перемещался к графику функции `y=x^2+500`, и чтобы на оси `y` были значения, соответствующие настоящему графику так же с единичным отрезком в 2.5 единиц (затем поменяю по необходимости).

Как я понимаю использование методов `set_xlim()` и `set_ylim()` не подходит. Нужна помощь!

Отрывок кода, по которому, если вы ставите галочку на `QCheckBox`, то показывается график на `self.ui.layoutCanvas`:

```py
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    ...
    def show_graph(self, state):
        # Если галочка стоит, то state = 2
        if state == 2:
            self.prep() # Функция, убирающая в конце символ, 
            # если тот является оператором, но ни над чем не оперирует и др.
            text = self.ui.lineEdit.text()
            self.ui.layoutCanvasWidget.setGeometry(QRect(10, 150, 321, 321)) # Растягиваем `layout` в нужный размер
            fig = Figure()
            graph = fig.add_subplot()
            graph.set_ylim(-10, 10)
            graph.set_xlim(-10, 10)
            x = numpy.linspace(-100, 100, 1000)
            try:
                y = eval(self.replace_(text))
            except:
                self.ui.lineEdit.setText('Ошибка')
                self.result_status = True
                return
            try:
                graph.plot(x, y)
            except: # Если график функции имеет вид y=k, где k - константа, то чертим прямой график
                graph.plot([-10, 10], [y, y])
            fig.set_facecolor("#F3F3F3") 
            canvas = FigureCanvasQTAgg(fig)
            self.ui.layoutCanvas.addWidget(canvas)
        else:
            for i in reversed(range(self.ui.layoutCanvas.count())): # Очищаем self.ui.layoutCanvas от графика функции
                self.ui.layoutCanvas.itemAt(i).widget().setParent(None)
            self.ui.layoutCanvasWidget.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 0, 0)) # Прячем self.ui.layoutCanvas, чтобы кнопки нажимались
    ...
```

Comment: Пределы осей, ` graph.set_ylim` устанавливайте уже после того, как вычислены значения точек y: `graph.set_ylim(min(y), max(y))`, можно округлить пределы вверх/вниз по вкусу ...